# Is there any place where I can get reusable swing "components"?

Tags: java, swing

I feel that components like graph, pie chart, bar graph, clocks, key boards etc can be considered as reusable components. There should be no need to code these things repeatedly.

Is there a place where I can get swing components like these which are well  tested, reliable, well commented and well documented ?

**EDIT -**

By the way, I am looking for components that -

1 - Can be used easily by professional and newbie java developers.
2 - Are actively maintained and were not abandoned years ago.
**3 - Free of cost and source code is public.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like libraries? I remember using JFreeChart for a project a couple of years ago, and it wasn't bad for some basic graphing

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

I don't know of any clock or keyboard widget libraries off the top of my head, though

Comment: partial answer. but ok.